# How to add an array Observer to an Array controller in Emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js, firebase

Here is my problem I wish to update a view controller with and Array controller which I update through a rest API. However I can't seem to find a way to dynamically update the view when the content of the array is changed in the controller.

How would I add an array observer to this code?

I am using JavaScript, with emberjs API and Firebase for the data persistence.

```
Sept.ResultsController = Em.ArrayController.extend({});

    Sept.ResultsController.reopenClass({
        content : [],
        find : function(){
            $.ajax({
                    url : "gamma.firebase.com/blablab.json",//changed for a privacy purpose
                    dataType : 'jsonp',
                    context : this,
                    success : function(response){
                        var i = 0;
                        for (var item in response){
                            for (var items in response[item]){
                                this.content = response;
                                i++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },this);
            return this.content;
        }
    });

    Sept.ResultsView = Em.View.extend({
        templateName: 'results',
        contentBinding: 'Sept.ResultsController'
    });
```

Comment: How are you populating `ResultsController`. `return this.content` after ajax might not work as you intend as ajax in asynchronous. You should use `someController.set('content', resultArray)` somewhere are you already doing this?

Comment: @sabithpocker I am having a similar problem. Even if there is an issue here with `this.content`, I think it would be very useful to show an example of how to update a view that is bind to an `ArrayController` if the content of the array changes.

Comment: I eneded up rebuilding my whole app ... the routing of the app was the problem, now working !

Comment: @Lunatikzx: Please add an answer that says what you did to solve this problem.

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham In fact to answer this i ended up rebuild the whole app. so the question can be closed. 
I used ember router to call a class that would be reopened and that updated the data in the View. And i had to change my storage solution due to the fact that firebase needs to be at least online once to work.